# What numeral system should be used for hi (Hindi) locale?

Tags: localization, locale, momentjs, hindi

Opinions seem to differ on what numeral system to use when localising software to Hindi:

## Java

### `hi`: Western Arabic

```
Locale hi = new Locale("hi")
System.out.format(hi, "%d", 123456)
-> 123456
```

### `hi_IN`: Devanagari

```
Locale hi_IN = new Locale("hi", "IN")
System.out.format(hi_IN, "%d", 123456)
-> १२३४५६
```

---

## JavaScript - nodejs

### `hi`: Western Arabic

```
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('hi').format(123456.7890));
-> 1,23,456.789
```

### `hi-in`: Western Arabic

```
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('hi-IN').format(123456.7890));
-> 1,23,456.789
```

---

## JavaScript - Firefox

### `hi`: Western Arabic

```
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('hi').format(123456.7890));
-> 1,23,456.789
```

### `hi-in`: Western Arabic

```
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('hi-IN').format(123456.7890));
-> 1,23,456.789
```

---

## `moment.js`

### `hi`: Devanagari

https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/locale/hi.js#L13-L36

## So...

Which is correct?  Or is there no definitive answer?